# Program that will randomly choose who makes a gift to whom. Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, shuffle

I am working on a code that draws between two arrays, who is making a present to whom.

I want to work like that:

1. User enters names in the input. Theese will be people that will take part in the draw. The program automatically displays the names in the container.
2. Array Players[] is being copied by Players2[] so we have two equal arrays.
3. When the user clicks the Start button, the program will draw elements from the second Players2[] array and write them next to elements from Players[] array, deleting them from the array one by one and writing down next to elements from Players[] that has been written down earlier.
4. In the end we got full Players[] array and empty Players2[] array but everybody knows, who they have to make present to, cause it's written on the screen.
5. The problem is the part when the program draw a random element in the Players2[] array and writes it down. The lottery works fine but the program does not check if there is the same name next to it. So that this person does not have to make a gift for themselves.

```js
let Players = [];
let Players2 = [];

const addBTN = document.getElementById('addBTN');
const onlyLetters = /^[a-zżźćóęśńłA-ZŻŹĆÓŁĘŚŃŁ ]+$/;
const refreshBTN = document.getElementById('refreshBTN');
const warningBTNyes = document.getElementById('warning-button-yes');
const warningBTNno = document.getElementById('warning-button-no');
const playersList = document.getElementById('playersList');
const playersList2 = document.getElementById('playersList2');
const startBTN = document.getElementById('startBTN');
const drawLotsBTN = document.getElementById('drawLotsBTN');

addBTN.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const input = document.getElementById('addPLAYER');
  const person = document.getElementById('addPLAYER').value;
  if (input.value == "") {
    console.log('error_empty_input');
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = "Wpisz imię osoby!";
  } else if (input.value.match(onlyLetters)) {
    console.log('good');
    Players.push(person);
    playersList.innerHTML = playersList.innerHTML + "<br>" + person;
    document.getElementById('addPLAYER').value = "";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.color = "green";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = "Powodzenie! Dodaj kolejną osobę.";
  } else {
    console.log('error_input');
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = "Coś jest nie tak z imieniem. Pamiętaj aby wprowadzać same litery!";
  }
});

refreshBTN.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('warning').style.display = "block";
});

warningBTNyes.addEventListener('click', function () {
  location.reload(true);
  document.getElementById('addPLAYER').value = "";
});

warningBTNno.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('warning').style.display = "none";
});

startBTN.addEventListener('click', function () {
  drawLotsBTN.disabled = false;
  const input = document.getElementById('addPLAYER');
  const person = document.getElementById('addPLAYER').value;
  if (input.value == "") {

  } else if (input.value.match(onlyLetters)) {
    console.log('good');
    Players.push(person);
    Players2.push(person);
    playersList.innerHTML = playersList.innerHTML + "<br>" + person;
    document.getElementById('addPLAYER').value = "";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.color = "green";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = "Powodzenie! Zaczynasz losowanie!";
  } else {
    console.log('error_input');
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = "Coś jest nie tak z imieniem. Pamiętaj aby wprowadzać same litery!";
  }
  document.getElementById('addPLAYER').disabled = true;
});

drawLotsBTN.addEventListener('click', function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < Players.length; i++) {
    if (Players2.length > 0) {
      randomPerson = Math.floor(Math.random() * Players.length);
      if (randomPerson != Players.indexOf(i)) {
        console.log(Players2[randomPerson]);
        playersList2.innerHTML = playersList2.innerHTML + "<br>" + Players2[randomPerson];
        Players2.splice(randomPerson, 1);
      } else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    } else{
      console.log('error_empty_array');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('IMG/ChristmasBackground.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}/*
.title {

}*/
.lotteryContainer {
  display: flex;
}
.tables {
  display: flex;
}
.warning {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px grey;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="warning" class="warning">
    <div class="warning-flex"> 
      <h1>Wszelkie wpisane imiona zostaną usunięte</h1>
      <div class="warning-buttons">
        <button id="warning-button-yes" class="warning-button-yes">Tak</button>
        <button id="warning-button-no" class="warning-button no">Nie</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lotteryContainer">
    <div class="left">
      <p>dodaj osobę</p>
      <div class="addPerson">
        <input required id="addPLAYER" type="text">
        <button id="addBTN">+</button>
        <p id="errorMSG"></p>
        <div class="refresh">
          <button id="refreshBTN">Od nowa</button>
          <button id="startBTN">Start</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>Uczestnicy</p>
      <div class="tables">
        <div class="tableLeft">
          <p id=playersList></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tableRight">
          <p id="playersList2"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button id="drawLotsBTN">Losuj</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<!-- <script src="app.js"></script> //-->
```

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this code? What is not working yet? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: "The problem is the part when the program draw a random element in the Players2[] array and writes it down. The lottery works fine but the program does not check if there is the same name next to it. So that this person does not have to make a gift for themselves."

The program draws a name, writes it down next to the person that will give the present, deletes it from the Players2[] array so this things work fine. The problem is, it doesn't check if on the left side, there is the same name.

drawLotsBTN event listener is the part when i don't know how to make it work just like desired.

Comment: I've tried to make it work with array.sort method but with no positive effects. I just think I don't fully understand how this code works right now...

Comment: Put that information in the question. Don't put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided below just focusses on how one does create kind of a [**Julklapp** or **Secret Santa**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Santa) list of participant tuples ... `[<donator>, <receiver>]` ... from an array of participants or, with the OP's words ... `player`s.

How such a list of players gets or will be aggregated/created in the first place is not part of this answer.

```js
function shuffleArray(arr) {
  let idx;
  let count = arr.length;

  while (--count) {
    idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (count + 1));
    [arr[idx], arr[count]] = [arr[count], arr[idx]];
  }
  return arr;
}

function createSecretSantaList(participantList) {
  return shuffleArray(
    [...participantList]
  )
  .map((participant, idx, arr) => [
    participant,
    arr[idx + 1] ?? arr[0]
  ]);
}
console.log(
  "createSecretSantaList(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'biz', 'buz']) ...",
  createSecretSantaList(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'biz', 'buz'])
);
console.log(
  "createSecretSantaList(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'biz', 'buz']) ...",
  createSecretSantaList(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'biz', 'buz'])
);
console.log(
  "createSecretSantaList(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'biz', 'buz']) ...",
  createSecretSantaList(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'biz', 'buz'])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit** after having had following conversation ...*

> @KolekcjaKolekcja ... Regarding the above provided list creating approach are there any questions left? – Peter Seliger
>
> > Yes theese answers weren't helpfull. I found a video on youtube perfectly answering my question. I don't understand what was the problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WldtatIo4w – Kolekcja Kolekcja
> >
> > > @KolekcjaKolekcja ... The algorithm presented in the video is way too complicated and also not efficient. In order to create a Secret Santa list one needs exactly a single array of names which will be shuffled by a [modern variant of the famous Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm). Then the creation of the giver/receiver pair/tuple is a "no brainer" mapping task. And one never runs into the problem or has to explicitly work around of a person being left for giving/donati[ng]* to itself.

Please OP have a look at the algorithm which creates two Secret Santa lists, one with 100 and another one with 100,000 participants/items ...

```js
function shuffleArray(arr) {
  let idx;
  let count = arr.length;

  while (--count) {
    idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (count + 1));
    [arr[idx], arr[count]] = [arr[count], arr[idx]];
  }
  return arr;
}

function createSecretSantaList(participantList) {
  return shuffleArray(
    [...participantList]
  )
  .map((participant, idx, arr) => [
    participant,
    arr[idx + 1] ?? arr[0]
  ]);
}

console.log(
  'list of 100 items numbered from 1 to 100.000 turned into a Secret Santa list, with additional log-result mapping on top ...\n',
  createSecretSantaList(
    Array.from(
      { length: 100 },
      (item, idx) => ++idx,
    )
  )
  .map(([donator, receiver]) =>
    [donator, receiver].join(' => ')
  )
  .join('\n')
)
console.log(
  'list of 100,000 items numbered from 1 to 100,000 turned into a Secret Santa list, with additional log-result mapping on top ...\n',
  createSecretSantaList(
    Array.from(
      { length: 100_000 },
      (item, idx) => ++idx,
    )
  )
  .map(([donator, receiver]) =>
    [donator, receiver].join(' => ')
  )
  .join('\n')
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @KolekcjaKolekcja ... Regarding the above provided list creating approach are there any questions left?

Comment: Yes theese answers weren't helpfull. I found a video on youtube perfectly answering my question. I don't understand what was the problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WldtatIo4w

Comment: @KolekcjaKolekcja ... The algorithm presented in the video is way too complicated and also not efficient. In order to create a Secret Santa list one needs exactly a single array of names which will be shuffled by a [modern variant of the famous Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm). Then the creation of the giver/receiver pair/tuple is a "no brainer" mapping task. And one never runs into the problem or has to explicitly work around of a person being left for giving/donation to itself.